# How to avoid unnecessary API calls with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still beginner to ReactJS and I'm having trouble rendering a list.

I don't know why, all the time calls are being made to my API. Since I don't put any dependency on useEffect, that is, I should only render my function once.

I don't understand why this is happening. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-shaw-3ot0ng?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const BASE_URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2";

  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = React.useState([]);

  const getAllPokemons = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/pokemon`);

    data.results.map((pokemon) => getPokeType(pokemon));
  };

  const getPokeType = async (pokemon) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(pokemon.url);

    setPokemons((prev) => [...prev, data]);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getAllPokemons();
  }, []);

  console.log(pokemons);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
        <p key={pokemon.id} style={{ color: "blue" }}>
          {pokemon.name}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It might come from the fact that your getPokeType method is async and this is causing the react lifecycle to act out.

Try this `const datas = await Promise.all(
      data.results.map((pokemon) => axios.get(pokemon.url))
    );
    setPokemons(datas);` instead of `data.results.map((pokemon) => getPokeType(pokemon));`

Comment: Here is a small refactor that gives the effect you want, as Marko mentioned. Then, you can set the state only once at the end, which is cleaner anyways. https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-leavitt-ngokv9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling `setPokemons` inside `getPokeType` (which is called for each data in part). Your useEffect is called just once (as expected) and the `${BASE_URL}/pokemon` call is executed just once too. But `getPokeType` is called 20 times and the `pokemons` state is changed 20 times as well (once for each instance from `data.results`).

What I would recommend in your case (instead of what you have now) is:

1. Create a list of all the pokemons and
2. Set the state just once at the end.

So something like:

```
  ...

  const getPokeType = async (pokemon) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(pokemon.url);
    return data;
  };
  const getAllPokemons = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/pokemon`);
    const pokemons = await Promise.all(
      data.results.map((pokemon) => getPokeType(pokemon))
    );
    setPokemons(pokemons);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getAllPokemons();
  }, []);
  ...
```

Comment: Just an additional note, because the Codesandbox react is running in strict mode, the component is actually rendering at least twice - because he is concatenating the previous state with the new state as well, it's causing more than 20 items to build up. Also because of the conflicting keys I believe it was triggering even more re-renders, at one point I saw up to 75 items in the current state.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue in my project the way I solved is by moving the function definition inside the useEffect

```
     React.useEffect(() => {
             const getAllPokemons = async () => {
             const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/pokemon`);

             data.results.map((pokemon) => getPokeType(pokemon));
         };
      getAllPokemons();
     }, []);
```

If this solves your problem please accept the answer.